# Protected property with an array of strings returns Illegal string offset 'options'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Im working with [this](https://github.com/joselfonseca/laravel-tactician) implementation of `Tactician` for Laravel.

When i follow [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joselfonseca/24ee0e96666a06b16f92), and create the `middleware` array i get an `Illegal string offset 'options'` error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Commands\TestCommand;
use App\Commands\TestHandler;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    protected $bus;
    protected $middleware = [
        'App\Commands\GenerateOrderValidator',
        'Joselfonseca\LaravelTactician\Middleware\DatabaseTransactions'
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bus = app('Joselfonseca\LaravelTactician\CommandBusInterface');
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->bus->addHandler(TestCommand::class, TestHandler::class);
        return $this->bus->dispatch(TestCommand::class, [], $this->middleware);
    }
}
```

But if i put the array directly on the `dispatch` method, it works fine, like this example:

```
return $this->bus->dispatch(TestCommand::class, [], [
            'App\Commands\GenerateOrderValidator',
            'Joselfonseca\LaravelTactician\Middleware\DatabaseTransactions'
        ]);
```

I know they are some similar issues solved about this, but i really want to understand, why its working in the `dispatch` method and not in the `property`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the Laravel already defines a property called `$middleware` in the Controller class (source code [here](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Controller.php)) and each item in this array is expected to have the following structure because is used internally for route middlewares handling:

```php
$this->middleware[] = [
    'middleware' => $m,
    'options' => &$options,
];
```

You should then rename your property to avoid clashes.

Comment: Working, i was suspecting was something directly related with Laravel, thanks mate!